# JOINs with conditon in HQL query?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hql

How can i write to HQL Query?
This is My Original scenario  I have two hbm files ADVMAgencyMaster.hbm.xml,ADVRoheader.hbm.xml corresponding pojo classes are  ADVMAgencyMaster.java,ADVroheader.java.

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.adv.hibernatebean.ADVMAgencyMaster" table="ADVMAGENCYMASTER" catalog="MEDIAERP">
        <id name="mamaid" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MAMAID" length="10" />
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="mamaname" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="MAMANAME" length="50" />
        </property>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.adv.hibernatebean.ADVRoheader" table="ADVTROHEADER" schema="MEDIAERP">
        <id name="trohiono" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="TROHIONO" />
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="advmagencymaster" class="com.adv.hibernatebean.ADVMAgencyMaster" fetch="select">
            <column name="TROHAMAID" />
        </many-to-one>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My oracle query is

```sql
SELECT MAMAID,MAMANAME,TROHIONO 
  FROM ADVAGENCYMASTER,ADVROHEADER 
 WHERE MAMAID(+)=TROHAMAID
```

Match records from both table that condition is `MAMAID(+)=TROHAMAID` in oracle. Pls tell how writer in HQL.

Comment: I rewrite this query.pls tell any solution for this question

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan pls see above code

Comment: please check out , tutorials. Might be helpful to you! [hibernate-relationship](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial)

Comment: why sir,if you give solution how to write this query in HQL

Comment: @FayeqAliKhan You ask hbm files and pojo class and i posted pls give solution

Answer (score 1):

Corresponding is HQL

```
  select header.advmagencymaster.mamaid,
         header.advmagencymaster.mamaname,header.trohiono 
         from ADVRoheader header
```

But In HQL it is better to retrieve entire object so that we can use the other properties also

```
   from ADVRoheader header 
   inner join 
   header.advmagencymaster master
```

HQL is not depending on the underlying database.It will be same for all databases(Oracle,Mysql,SQL server etc).only We need to change the Database connection in the main configuration file.

Your model classes will look like this

```
class ADVMAgencyMaster{
  private String mamaid;
 private String mamaname;  //getters and setters
}

class ADVRoheader{
 private String trohiono;
 private ADVMAgencyMaster advmagencymaster;     // Reference to the ADVMAgencyMaster
 //getters and setters}
```

You Already defined a many to one relation in xml

```
 <many-to-one name="advmagencymaster" class="com.adv.hibernatebean.ADVMAgencyMaster" fetch="select"> <column name="TROHAMAID" /></many-to-one>
```

So while Loading ADVRoheader object hibernate will load the inner object reference "advmagencymaster" also.

for this you need to specify lazy="false" instead of fetch="select".

lazy="true" - lazy loading it will load only parent object

lazy-"false" - eager loading it will load child(inner) object also with parent object.

add both hbm.xml files in to main configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml) as follows

```
 <mapping resource="com/ADVRoheader.hbm.xml"></mapping>
 <mapping resource="com/ADVRomaster.hbm.xml"></mapping>
```

just before session factory closing tag  here the mapping is happening with Database.

Usually for generator elements we need to use type integer and make the change in database also.

Extra filtering we can add 'where' clause after the main query.Here only joining condition is required and it is already handled by hibernate.

Comment: you already mapped the columns in your xml as follows <many-to-one name="advmagencymaster" class="com.adv.hibernatebean.ADVMAgencyMaster" fetch="select">
            <column name="TROHAMAID" />
        </many-to-one>

Comment: pls check the edited version.Make sure the generator value ie 'id' of each table  can be string, i think as it is auto incrementing it should be integer

Comment: it throws an exception

Comment: It throws an Exception :org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: header.ADVMAgencyMaster is not mapped.[select * from header.ADVMAgencyMaster master inner join ADVRoheader header]

Comment: what i'll do ADVRoheader.hbm.xml at  <many-to-one name="advmagencymaster" class="com.adv.hibernatebean.ADVMAgencyMaster" lazy="false"> <column name="TROHAMAID" /></many-to-one>..can u tell this is correct way ah???

Comment: add bith hbm.xml files in to main configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml) as follows                              <mapping resource="com/ADVRoheader.hbm.xml"></mapping>
<mapping resource="com/ADVRomaster.hbm.xml"></mapping>

just before session factory closing tag
</session-factory> here the mapping is happening with Database.

Comment: i changed in my advroheader.hbm.xml ,replace tag lazy="false" instead of fetch="select".onece again redepoly and run my application.once again throw same error..what can i do???

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: header.ADVMAgencyMaster is not mapped. [select master.mamaid,master.mamaname,header.trohiono 
   from ADVRoheader header 
   inner join 
   header.advmagencymaster master] org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:157)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
 at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)

Comment: pls check the edited version last part.adding your hbm.xml files into  hibernate configuration file in end portion of session factory tag

Comment: All tags are closing perfectly in all related files.You said change lazy="false" i also changed but query not working perfectly..but why u said edited version correction suppose if .xml files caught error means doesn't create sessionfactory.

Comment: if u know possible solution for this problem,pls reply me

Comment: pls try this "select header.advmagencymaster.mamaid,header.advmagencymaster.mamaname,header.trohiono 
  from ADVRoheader header"

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,

```
from  ADVMAgencyMaster master 
       inner join 
       ADVRoheader header
Where  master.mamaid = (userInputId)
```

With on Clause

```
from  ADVMAgencyMaster master 
       inner join 
       ADVRoheader header on master.mamaid = header.trohamaid
Where  master.mamaid = (userInputId) //optional, it will filter row as per user input
```

When the join type is inner , On Clause automatically acts/performs Where filter as well.

Comment: (userInputId) to filter rows as per your requirement!

Comment: how to specific my conditon in this query

Comment: want match this conditon, "master.mamaid=header.trohamaid"

Comment: It throws an Exception :org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ROH.ADVMAgencyMaster is not mapped.[select * from header.ADVMAgencyMaster master inner join ADVRoheader ROH]

Comment: @karthik.A.M Mapping updated in query, Use Class name in from clause(select query)

Comment: It throws an Exception :org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: header.ADVMAgencyMaster is not mapped.[select * from header.ADVMAgencyMaster master inner join ADVRoheader header]

Comment: sir i am using class name only after from clause

Comment: pls reply..still haven't conculed decision

Comment: @karthik.A.M , I dnt know whether your mapping is ok or there is some problem, just try to query single table one by one in select query to verify , whether table is outputting data or not.. if both tables in single select query working than do the join.